# Redirect www to non-www when using proxy pass

Tags: nginx, webserver, gunicorn, vhosts

I have these urls and I want to point `www` to `non-www` always.

```
https://es.site.com
https://www.es.site.com <---
```

This minimal vhost file redirect all `http` request to `https` requests when using `non-www`. It works fine.

```
http {
        server {
                listen 80 default_server;
                listen [::]:80 default_server;
                server_name es.site.com;
                return 301 https://es.site.com$request_uri;
        }

        #copy snippet below here

        server {
                listen 443 ssl http2;
                listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

                ssl on;

                root /home/xxx/myproject/app;

                location /static {
                        alias /home/xxx/myproject/app/static;
                }

                location / {
                        try_files $uri @gunicorn_proxy;
                }

                location @gunicorn_proxy {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                }

        }
}
```

I need to duplicate the first server block? I want to make the change in production, so I am just looking for a code review before.

Something like this, so I will have three server blocks?

```
server {
                listen 80 default_server;
                listen [::]:80 default_server;
                server_name www.es.site.com;
                return 301 https://www.es.site.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Should't the last `return 301 https://www.es.site.com$request_uri;` be `return 301 https://es.site.com$request_uri;`? You said you want all www to non-www

Comment: @TarunLalwani You are right. So in that case I can have only two server blocks. I mean `server_name example.org www.example.org;` ?

Comment: Yes. You can use the first one with `server_name es.site.com www.es.site.com;`

Comment: @TarunLalwani ok, thanks. I will make a test later. Now I can't test this type of things in prod.